# passing ajax variable to php

Tags: jquery

```
        function viewDetail(pid)
        {
               $.post("product.php", { data: pid});

               <?php
               $data = $_POST['data'];
               retrieve_product_detail($data);
            ?>
        }
```

i tried this method too, but value of 'pid' is not going to the function `retrieve_product_detail($data)` please help me i am so stuck soooooooooooon

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=pass+javascript+variable+to+php

Comment: is that JS function in a javascript file by any chance?

Comment: try to debug `$_POST` to see what it really contains.

Answer (score 0):

```
var url = "myurl/myurl.php";
var params = "param1=sth&param2=sth";
http.open("POST", url, true);

//header information along with the request
http.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
http.setRequestHeader("Content-length", params.length);
http.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");

http.onreadystatechange = function() {//Call a function when the state changes.
    if(http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200) {
        alert(http.responseText);
                //or do whatever you want to with the response
    }
}
http.send(params);
```

Comment: I think he asks about jQuery.